# Создание нестандртной клавиатуры в XamarinForms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, клавиатура, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе текста в Entry виртуальная клавиатура состояла только из цифр 0-9, точки и backspace.
Xamarin предлагает 7 стандартных вариантов клавиатуры, но ни один мне не подходит. Я находил несколько уроков по созданию кастомной клавиатуры, но единственное что в них понял - что весь код в них на Джаве и в моём проекте не работает.

Как средствами стандартной библиотеки Xamarin создать собственный вариант клавиатуры, описанный выше (если возможно)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Видели приложение "Сбербанк онлайн"? Там пин-код вводится не клавиатурой, а прямо интерфейсом. Вот и вы можете наделать нужных вам кнопок прямо в интерфейсе. Клавиатура не нужна при этом совсем.

Comment: Да, я пришёл к этому же выводу. Но всё же надеялся, что есть другой способ.